# Adjusting the audio volume of a remote pc

Tags: networking, windows-10, audio, remote

I have an Intel NUC running Windows 10 that is connected to my home cinema speakers which I use to listen to Spotify.

While I can change the volume of Spotify remotely using Spotify Connect, sometimes the system volume is lower than I like, usually because I was watching movies on the NUC the night before.

Is there any way to change the system volume from a remote system, over the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use vbscript to change volume using some utilities such as NirCmd (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216334)

Snippet:

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

// Increase the system volume by 20000 units (out of 65535)
oShell.Run("nircmd.exe changesysvolume 20000");
```

You can combine that with PsExec ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec ) which is a Microsoft Sysinternals tool.

Snippet (that is running ipconfig):

```
wshShell.run("cmd /k psexec \\REMOTEPC -u userhere -p " & password & " -s ipconfig /flushdns")
```

PsExec can actually run remote programs as if they are local, so you can probably set it up to simply launch the sound volume applet directly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your OS.

Windows 10 *pro* has Remote Desktop as one of its features which can be accessed from another device.

However, if you have any other OS then use [VNC](https://www.realvnc.com/en/) which can be installed on all major operating systems including many Linux distros

Comment: while in RDP, isn't the only audio device whose volume can be changed the remote audio device?